# Bash script kill command in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to kill all processes containing some string. I wrote script for doing this. However, when I execute it, it gets "Killed" signal after first iteration of for loop. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

executeCommand () {
 local pname="$1";
 echo $HOSTNAME;
 local  search_terms=($(ps aux | grep $pname | awk '{print $2}'))
 for pros in "${search_terms[@]}";  do
     kill -9 "$pros"
     echo $pros
 done
exit
}

executeCommand "$1"  # get the string that process to be killed contains
```

I execute it like `./my_script.sh zookeeper`.
When I delete the line containing `kill` command, `for loop` executes until end, otherwise, after first `kill` command, I get as an output "`Killed`" and program exits.

What is possible reason for this, and any other solution to reach my goal?

Comment: "Other solutions to reach [your] goal" -- have you considered `pkill`?

Comment: BTW, any chance your code might be running under a user account named  `zookeeper`?

Comment: nope. In fact if I output the PIDs from for loop and kill -9 them manually everything works. But when putting them all together, I am in trouble. I am checking your proposed solution now.

Comment: That you only get the error during scripted execution is behavior you should expect, and not be the slightest bit surprised by -- it's only while the loop is running that, for instance, `grep` (or other components of your script) are PIDs that actively exist and so *can* be found in the list and terminated.

Comment: Aside: Strongly suggest avoiding `.sh` extensions, which mean that if you rewrite a script in a different language you either need to rename the script and change every caller or live with a misleading name. And command name extensions simply aren't conventional on UNIX: You don't call `ls.elf`.

Comment: Don't use [`kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill) unless you know for a fact that `-15` (the default) and `-2` will not work.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your reply. I tried. When I use default `kill` the running process, (in my case `zookeeper`) does not stop.

Comment: pgrep might also be useful for finding process IDs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The silly (faulty, buggy) way to do this is to add `grep -v grep` to your pipeline:

```
# ${0##*/} expands to the name of the running script
# ...thus, we avoid killing either grep, or the script itself
ps aux | grep -e "$pname" | egrep -v "grep|${0##*/}" | awk '{print $2}'
```

The better way is to use a tool built for the job:

```
# pkill already, automatically, avoids killing any of its parent processes
pkill "$pname"
```

That said, matching processes by name is a bad practice to start with -- you'll also kill `less yourproc.log` or `vim yourproc.conf`, not just `yourproc`. Don't do it; instead, use a proper process supervision system (upstart, DJB daemontools, Apple launchd, systemd, etc) to monitor your long-running daemons and kill or restart them when needed.

---

By the way -- there's no need for a `for` loop at all: `kill` can be passed multiple PIDs on a single invocation, like so:

```
# a bit longer and bash-specific, but avoids globbing
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a pids \
  < <(ps auxw | awk -v proc="$pname" -v preserve="${0##*/}" \
      '$0 ~ proc && $0 !~ preserve && ! /awk/ { print $2 }' \
      && printf '\0')
kill -- "${pids[@]}"
```

...which could also be formulated as something like:

```
# setting IFS and running `set -f` necessary to make unquoted expansion safe
( IFS=$'\n'; set -f; exec kill -- \
  $(ps auxw | awk -v proc="$pname" -v preserve="${0##*/}" \
    '$0 ~ proc && $0 !~ preserve && ! /awk/ { print $2 }') )
```

Comment: Another option I could think of is `killall "$pname"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the pkill "$pname". It does not stop the process running. I check it from ps -aux | grep zookeeper. Maybe it needs some option like -9 like in kill. I changed the pipeline in a way you proposed. I get output like:                                                                  cloud-12
22770
23030
Terminated.                                                                                                        So not all processes are killed again. Somehow I get a signal in the middle

Comment: Grepping `ps` is the wrong way to go about killing a process tree reliably in the first place. `fuser -k`, after identifying (or arranging to have) a file open by the process tree that needs to die, is your friend.

Comment: btw, `pkill` has safeties against killing a parent process of the shell that invokes it. You want those safeties, here; consider running `pkill -9`.

Comment: I tried your solution, the output is same. So I get    `cloud-12`  `Killed`. Whatever I write under `kill -9  ${pids[@]}"` does not execute. Can it be system signal, because I overuse the resources, although I don't think so.

Comment: One thing *I* would do is put a `tee procs-to-kill.log` in your pipeline just *before* the `awk` command; that way you can review that logfile to see what's actually getting killed.

Comment: so, after a moment of thought -- what else it's matching is the `zookeeper` in `./my_script zookeeper` -- hence needing to exclude `my_script`, just as you exclude `grep`.

Comment: @JeyhunKarimov, ...btw, if you last evaluated this answer before the most recent round of edits, you might do so again.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tested with updated version of your post. It does not give me a `Killed` signal. However, it does not kill all processes. I assume it is becasue `kill --` command, as it is not `kill -9`. I changed it to `kill -9`, it gives me again `Killed` signal. While killing processes, maybe it starts randomly (the order of `PIDs`) and if parent process is killed, the reference to child is changed and its `PID` is also changed in runtime of script. Maybe this is the reason of anomaly I face.

Comment: @JeyhunKarimov, yes, I leave it to you (and welcome you to) add the `-9`. I won't suggest it myself, because using SIGKILL except in cases of absolute necessity is bad practice. BTW, it would be `kill -9 --`, with the `-9` *before* the `--`.

Answer (score 0):

grep will show , it's own process . it should be removed using grep -v option

Try like this

```
for i in ` ps -ef | grep "$pname" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
do    
  kill -9 $i
done
```

Comment: I edited to add the missing code formatting, but there are still some bugs in the code.

Comment: better as-edited, but still buggy -- `$pname` doesn't expand with the whitespace where it shouldn't be, will break due to unquoted expansions if `IFS` is set to a value that doesn't include whitespace (or especially if it's set to a value that includes digits that can exist in PIDs), and using backticks instead of `$()` is frowned on in modern (post-1991 POSIX-sh-standard) shells.

Comment: cloud-12
22770
23030
Terminated. This is output I get. And not all zookeeper processes are killed. The killed one's PIDs are outputted then "Terminated" message is displayed